# How to make a visual rendering of a parse tree in Java?

Tags: java, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree, parse-tree

Quite new to ANTLR4 and I have written grammar for infix arithmetic and then using Visitor to parse and convert that infix expression to postfix expression.

Next thing I want is to make a visual rendering of the infix expression parse tree without the rule names but I am not sure how to go about making it. Any help will be appreciated.

ExpAnalyser.g4:

```
grammar ExpAnalyser;

//Infix Arithmetic

eval : additionExp;

additionExp : multiplyExp(PLUS multiplyExp | MINUS multiplyExp)* ;

multiplyExp : unaryExp(MULT unaryExp | DIV unaryExp)* ;

unaryExp :  MINUS atomExp | atomExp ;

atomExp :  NUMBER | LPAREN eval RPAREN ;

//Tokenizers : Lexers
MULT : '*' ;
DIV : '/' ;
MOD : '%' ;
PLUS : '+' ;
MINUS : '-' ;

LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;

NUMBER : [0-9]+ (['.'][0-9]+)? ;

COMMENT : '//' .+? ('\n'|EOF) -> skip ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the AST into a graph in something like `JGraphT` and the export it in some common graph format. Then I'd use generic graph rendering software like Graphviz or yEd to render the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I convert AST into graph using `JGraphT `? I haven't heard about it before so I am not sure. Could you maybe provide me with examples or tutorials for this?

Comment: @AaySquare Traverse the AST and build the graph. It should actually be quite straightforward. Sorry, I don't have resources to guide you through this.